# Encrypt home folder after installation

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I installed manjaro more than 2 years ago.

I did not choose to encrypt my home folder during installation.

Now, I think I want this. Can I do this now?

Answer (score 0):

This helps:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Encrypting_a_data_directory

I am actually not encrypting the whole home right now. I am scared of messing up, my disk space is limited, and there is a bunch of stuff which is overkill to be encrypted (e.g. Music).